# SQL Query: Retrieve columns with different condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to retrieve multiple columns with different condition from the different table.
What i have as below

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE Price >= 0 Price < 10) AS 'Group1',
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE Price >= 10 AND Price < 20) AS 'Group2',
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE Price >= 20 AND Price < 30) AS 'Group3',
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 WHERE Price >= 0 Price < 10) AS 'Group4',
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 WHERE Price >= 10 AND Price < 20) AS 'Group5',
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 WHERE Price >= 20 AND Price < 30) AS 'Group6'
```

Just wonder is there any better way to restructure a better query for above condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is,

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN Price >= 0 Price < 10 THEN 1 END) AS 'Group1',
        SUM(CASE WHEN Price >= 10 AND Price < 20 THEN 1 END) AS 'Group2',
        SUM(CASE WHEN Price >= 20 AND Price < 30 THEN 1 END) AS 'Group3',
        SUM(CASE WHEN Price >= 0 Price < 10 THEN 1 END) AS 'Group4',
        SUM(CASE WHEN Price >= 10 AND Price < 20 THEN 1 END) AS 'Group5',
        SUM(CASE WHEN Price >= 20 AND Price < 30 THEN 1 END) AS 'Group6'
FROM    table2
```

Comment: Why is it better, what's the difference? Also there are 2 tables in the question.

Comment: @Alexey it will only pass on the table once, rather than calling 6 `SELECT` statement

Comment: @J W But it will not do full scanning because of price restrictions. So all together looks the same.

Comment: @Alexey what did query analyzer tells you?

Comment: @J W Yes, you are right, it's faster because of less scanning. Sorry. But anyway there are 2 tables in the question.

Comment: @Alexey, thanks for your answer. May i know how to check query performance?

Comment: @My2ndLovE I've just used EXPLAIN SELECT ... in MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Adding up table1 to the above wonderful query by J W.

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN T1.Price >= 0 Price < 10 THEN 1 END) AS 'Group1',
        SUM(CASE WHEN T1.Price >= 10 AND Price < 20 THEN 1 END) AS 'Group2',
        SUM(CASE WHEN T1.Price >= 20 AND Price < 30 THEN 1 END) AS 'Group3',
        SUM(CASE WHEN T2.Price >= 0 Price < 10 THEN 1 END) AS 'Group4',
        SUM(CASE WHEN T2.Price >= 10 AND Price < 20 THEN 1 END) AS 'Group5',
        SUM(CASE WHEN T2.Price >= 20 AND Price < 30 THEN 1 END) AS 'Group6'
FROM    table1 T1, table2 T2
```